# ELIFECYCLE error with webpack while trying to run dev server

Tags: npm, webpack

I've been trying to solve this problem from morning and more than half of my day is wasted trying to re-configure webpack, remove and reinstall packages to see why it's going wrong. I'm not really sure what's happening but I get this new "package-lock.json" file every time I try to configure.

I started to get familiar with webpack as early as yesterday and I was really happy when I used it along with react and react-bootstrap yesterday. 
I really feel like the problem is with npm but I didn't uninstall it.

I uninstalled/deleted the node_modules folder several times and reinstalled them back but it doesn't work either!

[**EDIT**]

I just found out that there's something weird going on, I have this package-lock.json file and it seems like this file is preventing from any npm module installation. I checked my node_modules folder and I find only fsevents module and nothing else. I tried to run npm install but nothing happens.

What I have done from yesterday
- update npm
- clean cache i guess.

Here's my error 
[image: console image]

And this is my webpack configuration file

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports = {
      entry: "./app/index.js",
      output : {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: 'babel-loader'
          }
          ,{
            test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader'
              },{
                loader: 'css-loader'
              },{
                loader: 'sass-loader'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      devServer: {
        contentBase: __dirname + '/build',
        port: 3000
      }
    }
```

Please help me through this!

Comment: `webpack is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: Read the whole thing, I've installed webpack localling in the project. webpack's docs also don't recommend installing webpack globally

Comment: Wait a sec @robertklep Something is wrong, When I run `npm install` nothing installs! and there is  this package-lock.json file, do you think that is the root cause?

Comment: I don't know how Windows works with locally installed packages, but I'm pretty sure that the `webpack` CLI tool won't be in your path. If `npm install` doesn't install anything, it's probably because it assumes that all dependencies are already up-to-date. You can remove it and re-run `npm install`.

Comment: Should I reinstall npm and node?

Comment: I don't think that will solve anything. When installed locally, the `webpack` CLI tool should be installed in `.node_modules\.bin\`, so if you have that directory in your `$PATH` (or the Windows-equivalent of that) it may work (at least the Webpack-part).

Comment: Actually, I tried to delete the node_modules folder and also the package-lock.json file. And then I ran the `npm install` command. Doing this resulted in the package-lock.json file being recreated and non of my dependencies were installed.

Comment: In that case, reinstalling Node may help, but it might just be that you need to update `npm` (`npm i npm -g`).